Which crops could feed lots of people in a world that has lost a lot of arable land?
Imagine a world in which a lot of arable land was simply lost to persistent organic / heavy metal pollution or salinization or soil degradation or all three. The world is left with a lot of hungry people but not nearly as much land to grow food with, thus highly efficient and intensive use of land is needed - what crops would be best? Presume they have synthetic fertilizer and such, how might this be done? I have been researching the calories per hectare per day of various crops and sweet potatoes and potatoes appear to be the best out of everything (rice and corn not very far behind), but obviously the world cannot survive very well on only potatoes and sweet potatoes. Would soy beans be the best way to get protein? Would grazing animals likely be kept around if they could graze on rocky or depleted grassland unsuitable for crops and provide fat in the form of milk and meat? What would you think is the best option to try and squeeze the most nutrition out of very little land in this world?

most livestock was grazed on unfarmable land, it is a way of increasing your food supply.

If you search this site (always a good idea before asking a question), you'll find that this question has been asked many times in many forms. It's likely that yours is a duplicate of this question. Could you look at it and maybe a few of the others and explain how your question is significantly different from those? Thanks.

I think the difference is I didn't mention an apocalypse - my question is specifically about a land scarcity situation. Nuclear bombs is a whole different situation - it would alter the climate, destroy our capacity to produce synthetic fertilizer, leave radioactivity everywhere, etc. Land scarcity is a different question because I'm trying to imagine a world sort of doing the best with limited land, not a nuclear hellscape.

@calvinpeterson How the land became scarce is just an aesthetic of the story. The other question didn't mention anything about altered climates any more than you did. Radiation is mostly gone after about 7 years. So... unless you can explain why the southwestern climates focused on in the other question doesn't represent the limited arable land in yours.... Like I said, we've been asked this a lot. The odds are good that yours is a duplicate of one of them. What's really different?

@JBH I disagree that the questions are too similar. In case of post apocalyptic settings industrial solutions are usually out of the picture, the industry is gone. In this case the industry is well and the remaining farmable land can be utilised to maximum capacity. Big machines and industrial quantities of fertilizer seem to be available. Constraints in the linked question: "easy to grow, hardy, and calorie and nutrient dense" from that only "calorie and nutrient dense" seem to apply here. Also this question adds the constraint of "space efficient".

@datacube You're judging the back story. The previous question did not indicate any limiitations that made this question different. The word "apocalypse" isn't, of itself, sufficient to rationalize a difference. Further, Worse is word smithing to find differences. "Efficient" is what people do right now, growing food sources that maximize the productivity of farms. Without very speicific definitions that preculude making excuses, it's impossible to claim any difference between the questions.

Needs narrowing to a single question. Just to note, grasses are great - they don't pick up and transfer to grazers all the heavy-metals, but legumes (beans/peas/lentils of various types) unfortunately do.

Most places in the world are already major producers of their own ideal crops
While Potatoes and Sweet Potatoes can outproduce Wheat and Corn, they can only do that in climates and soil conditions which are ideal for Potatoes and Sweet Potatoes.  Places where you mostly see Wheat and Corn grown are often bad environments to grow Potatoes and Sweet Potatoes in and vice versa; so, there is actually no such things as a single crop that all of humanity should pivot too.
Instead, you should looks at maps of where you plan to render inhospitable to agriculture and work it out from there. This report should give you a good idea of what areas grow what crops, and how much those areas are currently being used to capacity. So, to figure out how food production would change, you need to blackout the regions that will be lost and remove those crops from the global food budget, and then identify remaining places that are not contaminated and are poorly utilized, and increase the production of the crops that already grow there.
Your second step would be to identify highly inefficient sources of food.  A lot of your red meats like cow and lamb will need to be scaled way back since industrial animal husbandry typically involves feeding them human edible crops like wheat and corn. But if you go back to a grazing model of husbandry, then you could raise much smaller numbers of red meat animals off of more rugged wild grasses in places that other things don't grow so well. It would also help to transition more toward poultry, pork, and fish farms since these require much less feed per pound of meat.
The third thing to change is how food is processed.  For example, cereal grains like wheat contain a lot of the same essential nutrients as fruit and raw vegetables like vitamin C & D, but milling these grains so you can store them as flour destroys a lot of these neutrainats meaning that we need to turn to less efficient crops to fill in gaps.  So, if you transition away from flour products like bread, tortillas, and pasta and replace them with unmilled cereal products like oatmeal, couscous, and rice, then you will reduce your need for fruits and vegetables which are generally not as efficient of crops.  This means that places where you see that currently grow both cereal grains and other crops can transition more heavily towards the grains.
Fourth, there are some crops that just produce very little calories per acre like spinach, celery, cucumbers, and most kinds of herbs and spices. So, if you see these things grown in the same zones as cereal grains or potatoes, then phasing out the one for the other could theoretically increase your overall calorie production, but only in some cases.  A lot of times, these are grown as succession crops where your staple crops can not be grown at a given time of year.  More likely than not you will be replacing winter crops like spinach and celery with carrots or summer crops like cucumbers with some kind of beans.
Or you could just fix the bad soil...
This  is a bit of a frame challenge, but if you identify exactly why these lands have become barren you can just fix them.  This solves a much bigger problem than just what kind of plant to grow to maximize calories.  Heavy metal pollution, salinization, and soil degradation can all be fixed simply by changing your crop instead of abandoning the farmland all together.
Sunflowers are exceptional at removing a wide range of heavy metals from soil with the ability to take up 95% of the uranium in soil in under a month.  If the penetration is deeper, you can plant willow, but the cleanup may take several years instead of months to complete.  Either way, just harvest and bury the plants deep underground to dispose of the toxic metals, and then you're back to having good soil having only lost a little bit of useful growing time.  The only thing that would cause heavy metal damage on a large scale all at once would  be a nuclear war... but if that happens, your demand for food will naturally drop much faster than soil contamination.
Salinization is also easy to address. Salinization is one the the leading causes of desertification, and it comes from a lack of biodiversity in our planting practices.  Woody plants like saltier soil than herbaceous plants, and will actually desalinate the soil over time; so, if your land gets too salty for wheat or potatoes, just plant an orchard or farm lumber in its place.  The trees will remove the extra salt and provide other valuable resources in the interim until the soil is back to being good for herbaceous crops.  If you just try to use your small amounts of remaining unsalinated land for high calorie monoculture potato farming, you will actually accelerate the problem instead of fixing it.
Lastly, soil degradation is typical a side effect of monoculture farming.  There are many edible permacultures that are known to build up soil by creating full cycle symbiosis either through crop rotation or companion planting.  This can be more labor intensive than monoculture farming; so, it may increase the price of food in the short term, but will slowly increase how much food your civilization can produce over time by reclaiming your ruined soil.
The only soil problem that cannot be fixed just by changing your crops is groundwater depletion which might eventually make far inland farming unsustainable in places that currently rely on well water to meet agricultural demands, but even this could be remediated with a system of pipelines that pump water from highly rainy regions directly to drought sensitive zones.

"just fix them" lol'ing at this. Any time I hear the word "just", I repeat the sentence without the word to see how badly it changes the meaning. "Just change the gravitational constant of the universe.." -Q

One nit I'd add is that there are varieties of corn (maize) that grow well from the tropics to the fringes of the subarctic. A human can't live on just corn though, due to some missing nutrients.

@RobertRapplean But fixing bad soil is not that difficult at all. In most cases, it's just a matter of planting one crop instead of another. The only reason we don't do it more IRL is because the current state of the world allows one to save pennies on the dollar to let good land go bad pressing the repeat button on the same crop over and over again.  As global food shortages drive up food prices, the inefficiency of abandoning farmland will outweigh the efficiency of monoculture farming.

@T.E.D. Part of that is variant strains and part of it is because they grow fast and can be planted in the season that works best for them.  So in very cold regions, you might grow corn in summer and spinach or potatoes in the mid seasons, but in hot climates, you might grow corn in the winter and melons or cucumbers in the midseasons. Bigger restrictions are actually your more short term weather patterns.

For example, while wheat can handle strong winds pretty well, potato stems are very delicate and a crop can be easily ruined in a minor storm; however, wheat takes time to adjust to quick drops in temperature; so, if you live somewhere that experiences sudden and severe temperature changes during your growing season, potatoes might be more resilient.

@Nosajimiki - Honestly, a lot of it is because it was domesticated in Mexico where there isn't a lot of territory (compared to other grain staples) at the same latitude. So it had to be hybridized (purposely or incidentally) over more than a millennium into usable forms to reach the rest of North America. A consequence of the North/South axis of the Americas vs the East/West one of Eurasia.

Not quite. You're thinking of nutrient shortages. Rotating crops adjusts the amount of nitrogen, etc, in soil, but it doesn't fix an issue where the microbiome dies off. Currently, it's cheaper to dump piles of fertilizer on your soil so you don't have to worry about crops that consume all of the N/P/K. It's harder to fix soil that's been poisoned by arsenic or cadmium.

@RobertRapplean No, I mean contaminated soil too.  Arsenic and Cadmium can both be removed with hyperaccumulator cover crops you just need to pick the right cover crop for the contaminate.  Chinese Brake Fern is often used in Asia to can remove Cadmium from Rice paddies and Cress a really good Arsenic accumulator.

Hydroponics
Hydroponics is the art of farming with no soil.
Quoting the linked article:

From 1943 to 1946, Daniel I. Arnon served as a major in the United States Army and used his prior expertise with plant nutrition to feed troops stationed on barren Ponape Island in the western Pacific by growing crops in gravel and nutrient-rich water because there was no arable land available. (emphasis added)


Calvin Peterson, welcome. With land in short supply you would want to not grow one "best" crop but many different crops all together. The technical term for this is companion planting: you essentially create a simplified ecosystem in which all plants are either edible themselves, or support the growth of plants that are edible. It's much more labor-intensive than a monoculture and a nightmare to mechanise, but then you have all these hungry people who would be only too happy to provide the labor. In this way you also avoid the risk of your one best crop failing due to weather being too dry, or too cold, or too wrong in some other way, and everyone starving all at once;  the more crops you have, the more likely that something, somewhere will thrive in whatever the weather turns out to be.
For animals, consider poultry, rodents, pigs and fish rather than big grazers. They are all quick to breed and to grow, small enough to be best understood as edible pets, and provide additional products and/or services to the companion agriculture. Poultry will happily eat up the pests from your fields; rabbits will eat the parts of your crop plants which are inedible to humans; pigs will eat all sorts of leftovers and convert them into fat; and muck from the bottom of a fish pond makes excellent fertiliser, as does the manure of all the other animals mentioned above. You may also want to keep some smaller breeds of goats, especially those which also produce wool.

You can wash land.. aka, drainage it,  irrigate it or just hope for rain and push the outflowing water into the sea. This is how land which was once part of the ocean eventually becomes farmable. Aka leaching .. https://www.fao.org/4/x5871e/x5871e04.htm
While you leach it, you want to graze it. Hyperdense, one crop monocultures fail after a while by the way. The fungis and parasites just love it when the same things grows over and over again in the same spot. This is why even with one crop beeing more profitable, farmes have a "rotation" in many parts of the world.
